# How to move and transpose data from a varied number of columns about different itens?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with data of 18 thousand itens that come from a SAP program and I need to organize them in lines of content. The part numbers in columns A and C must be a match (the number in C column should be positioned in line with the first time it appears in column A), and the description provided in column C should be transposed to this line of match (copy + paste special transpose then delete from the column).

My idea for a code is something like this (im not a programmer):

1. Select the region of interest in columns B, C and D;
2. In column A, find the first cell with a match for the part number in column C for the selected interval - save this line;
3. Cut the interval;
4. Paste the selected region (step 1) in column B of saved line in step 2;
5. Copy the description in column D and paste special (transpose) in column E of the saved line;
6. In column D, select the content from saved line+1 until there's no more data in the cells of the column and delete;
7. End.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zf1maftGdCfupdAA7R0TNc6lzPnQrJ0j/view?usp=sharing (this is a small part of the actual sheet im working on).

Macro code is currently the following:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B20:D22").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D8:D10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("D9:D10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Lines 1 and 5 are examples of how it should look in the end (I must do the same with the next part numbers in column C and A). The macro should move the data until the first time the part number appears in column A, do the match and transpose description from column to line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] or [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: As Pᴇʜ mentioned, you'll need to show what you've done so far, and ask a specific question. A good start is to use the macro recorder in Excel, do the actions you've described, and start working from the code it generates.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering. Ive just put the initial code as an edit. Thats how it should be done for the next part number. My question is how to make it work for every next item in the sheet as a macro. Identify the "stop regions" and take next items to match with their spots in column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReOrganizeData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")  'define your worksheet

    Dim LastRow As Long  'find last used row in column D
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    'find first row with data in column B
    Dim StartRow As Long
    If ws.Cells(1, "B").Value = vbNullString Then
        StartRow = ws.Cells(1, "B").End(xlDown).Row
    Else
        StartRow = 1
    End If

    Dim MatchedRow As Double
    Dim EndRow As Long

    Do While StartRow < LastRow  'loop through all data
        'find end row
        EndRow = ws.Cells(StartRow, "B").End(xlDown).Row - 1
        If EndRow > LastRow Then EndRow = LastRow  'check for last row overflow

        'match data in column C with data in column A
        MatchedRow = Application.Match(ws.Cells(StartRow, "C").Value, ws.Columns("A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(MatchedRow) Then
            'check if matched row is free
            If ws.Cells(MatchedRow, "D").Value <> vbNullString Then
                MsgBox "The row " & MatchedRow & " where I need to write data is not empty. Something went wrong.", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If

            'move data B and C
            ws.Cells(MatchedRow, "B").Resize(1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(StartRow, "B").Resize(1, 2).Value
            ws.Cells(StartRow, "B").Resize(1, 2).Clear

            'transpose data D
            ws.Cells(MatchedRow, "D").Resize(1, EndRow - StartRow + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(ws.Cells(StartRow, "D").Resize(EndRow - StartRow + 1, 1).Value)
            ws.Cells(StartRow, "D").Resize(EndRow - StartRow + 1, 1).Clear
        Else
            MsgBox "Data '" & ws.Cells(StartRow, "C").Value & "' could not be matched with column A.", vbExclamation
        End If

        'set new start row
        StartRow = EndRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Using this data …

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Input data of "DataSheet".</sup>*

… it will output this:

[image]
*<sup>Image 2: Data in "DataSheet" after transformation.</sup>*

Comment: It worked! Exactly the way i needed Thank you very much for helping!