# Copy rows based on info in the first column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of data (item description) for 18 thousand items that appear a lot of times in the datasheet (the amount of times they repeat is random).

The first time the item appears on the list the description is shown, but for the next times there's only the part number in the first column.

The initial sheet:
[image]

How it should be:
[image]

The datasheet: [In Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zf1maftGdCfupdAA7R0TNc6lzPnQrJ0j/view?usp=sharing)

I couldn't make something reproducible for the whole sheet (including the random intervals without description data).

The idea is to have a match for every cell in columns A and C (as shown in the pictures).

I tried the following code, applying it column by column, but after some of them it goes wrong.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Area As Range, LastRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
      LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
    For Each Area In ActiveCell.EntireColumn(1).Resize(LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
        Area.Value = Area(1).Offset(-1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57361373/edit) to include the code you do have?

Comment: This can be accomplished with a very simple loop, check the value in column B, if it's blank then copy the row from above, iterate...

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I didn't put the code because I don't think it is useful at all... I've tried to record a macro but it's of course only applicable for the selected rows in the first time.

Comment: @dwirony Yes! I've been trying to do exactly that.. however with no success..

Comment: @PedroGhizzo It is similar to the code I gave you in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293559/how-to-move-and-transpose-data-from-a-varied-number-of-columns-about-different-i). So copy that code, and loop again through column B as I did in this code and copy each row down until `End Row` instead of the transforming actions there. It is very similar. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Populate()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 10)).Value = _
            Range(Cells(i - 1, 2), Cells(i - 1, 10)).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You ofcourse have an option to do this using VBA, but you can also achieve this without VBA.

With Goto Special feature in excel, you can select all the blank cells and enter the formula to refer the respective cell above.

You can checkout the steps at the following link:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/02/fill-blanks-excel/

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your answer! I think I can't use this "GoTo Special" feature because there are some descriptions with different "sizes" in my sheet, so sometimes the blanks should stay as blanks (for example in row 8 in the second image). So perhaps VBA is the only way... I'm just not sure how to make it work. Not experienced with anything bigger than a simple macro :(